# Post to django view from another view

Tags: python, django, post, django-views

Facing some constraints in a website, I was obligated to try to post data to some view from another view (I suppose it does make sense), like:

```
def view1(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
          value = request.POST.get('h1')
     ''' '''
```

And in my view2, I would do something like:

```
def view2(request):

    if constraint:
          python.post(/url/view1/,data={'h1':1}) # Doesn't exist
          # Just a demonstration
```

Is there a way to do what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) package to send request to other URLs, the question is "**why**" ??.

Why not extract the code of view1 in a utility function and call int from view2?

If you need to use an new HTTP request, I suggest to use the Django `reverse()` function to the the URL from the `urls.py` configuration (refer to the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ko/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) )

Comment: It's just because I have a view that handle some stuff, and I need to send the data needed from another view

Comment: just asking if you really need to send a new request. why don't extract the view's code in a function and call it ??

Comment: awesome. good point! I did this for many other views, I can't believe I didn't think about for that case

Comment: Sometimes third-parties ask directly about this, e.g. [djoser](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/social_endpoints.html#provider-auth) (step 4).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [requests](https://github.com/requests/requests) library to do this.

Comment: the link attached is broken

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at Python Requests: I found it in in Python forum to print which could be modified to post.

```py
import requests

req = requests.Request('POST','http://stackoverflow.com',headers={'X-Custom':'Test'},data='a=1&b=2')
prepared = req.prepare()

def pretty_print_POST(req):
    """
    At this point it is completely built and ready
    to be fired; it is "prepared".

    However pay attention at the formatting used in 
    this function because it is programmed to be pretty 
    printed and may differ from the actual request.
    """
    print('{}\n{}\n{}\n\n{}'.format(
        '-----------START-----------',
        req.method + ' ' + req.url,
        '\n'.join('{}: {}'.format(k, v) for k, v in req.headers.items()),
        req.body,
    ))

pretty_print_POST(prepared)
```